# remove repeating data from Oracle SQL*Plus query

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

I am currently building a database system using oracle 10g. I have developed a query that shows an instance of an event, the customer who requested the event and the staff assigned to the event. My query returns all the correct results but I wanted to know if there is a way to delete the repeating data. For each staff member assigned the result returns the event and customer details. I have attached a picture. Is there a way to return the customer and event details  only once in their columns and the corresponding records of staff assigned in that columns?

This my code

```
COLUMN E_ID FORMAT A7
COLUMN E_NAME FORMAT A20
COLUMN E_STIME FORMAT A30
COLUMN E_FTIME FORMAT A30
COLUMN E_COST FORMAT 9999999.99
COLUMN ET_ET_ID FORMAT A5
COLUMN V_V_ID FORMAT A5
COLUMN C_C_ID FORMAT A5
COLUMN C_FNAME FORMAT A10
COLUMN C_LNAME FORMAT A10
COLUMN S_S_ID FORMAT A5
COLUMN S_FNAME FORMAT A10
COLUMN S_LNAME FORMAT A10
COLUMN S_TASK FORMAT A20
COLUMN S_CNUM FORMAT 9999999
COLUMN ST_DESC FORMAT A20
SELECT E_ID, E_NAME, EVENT.C_C_ID ,C_FNAME, C_LNAME, E_STIME, E_FTIME, E_COST, EVENT.ET_ET_ID, EVENT.V_V_ID, EVENT_STAFF.S_S_ID, S_FNAME, S_LNAME, S_TASK, S_CNUM, STAFFTYPE.ST_DESC 
FROM CUSTOMER, EVENT, EVENT_STAFF, STAFF, STAFFTYPE
WHERE EVENT.E_ID = 'E000004'
AND EVENT.C_C_ID = CUSTOMER.C_ID
AND EVENT.E_ID = EVENT_STAFF.E_E_ID
AND EVENT_STAFF.S_S_ID = STAFF.S_ID
AND STAFF.ST_ST_ID = STAFFTYPE.ST_ID;
```

The results in SQL plus is as shown [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the [`BREAK ON` directive](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14356/toc.htm) in SQL*Plus is for. Add to your `COLUMN` formatting directives:

```
BREAK ON E_ID ON E_NAME ...
```

listing all columns where you want to omit duplicates. Don't forget to use `ORDER BY` to ensure that records for each event and customer return in the right sequence.